# preg_replace to remove all words beginning with http:// and ending with a space

Tags: php, url

i got an idea to remove all links from a string with PHP.

i need a preg_replace to remove and strip all words beginning with :

http://   or  https://  or www. or www3. or ftp://

and ending with a white space.

example : hello http://dsqdsq.com/fdsfsd?fsdflsd enjoy !

it's will be : hello enjoy !

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```
$output = preg_replace('!\b((https?|ftp)://)?www3?\..*?\b!', '', $input);
```

which:

- Starts at a word boundary (`\b`);
- Optionally begins with http://, https:// or ftp://; and
- Has a domain name beginning with www. or www3.

That and all text up to the next word boundary is then deleted.

**Note:** Using `\b` is generally superior than checking for spaces. `\b` is a zero-width (meaning it consumes no part of the input) that matches the beginning of the string, the end of the string, the transition from a word to a non-word character or the transition from a non-word to a word character.

Comment: +1 for \b ! Really nice operator to know! You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'hello http://dsqdsq.com/fdsfsd?fsdflsd enjoy !';
$stripped_string = preg_replace('; ((ftp|https?)://|www3?\.).+? ;', ' ', $string);
```

**Update**: Here is with \b instead of spaces, which will work better. Big thanks to cletus!

```
$string = 'hello http://dsqdsq.com/fdsfsd?fsdflsd enjoy !';
$stripped_string = preg_replace(';\b((ftp|https?)://|www3?\.).+?\b;', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Doesn't this require a space at the beginning - i.e. lines starting with a URL won't match?

Answer (score 0):

something like this? just off the top of my head without checking

```
/(http:\/\/(.*?)\s)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. try

```
$pattern=array(
        '`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si',
        '`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si'
        );
$output = "http://$1";
$input = // set some url here;
preg_replace($pattern,$output,$input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Cletus doesn't work properly because . (dot) is also word boundary so we should use whitespace marker \s instead of word bouadry at the end:

```
$output = preg_replace('!\b((https?|ftp)://)?www3?\..*?\s!', '', $input);
```